# Buttons on my bluetooth headset aren't working

Tags: bluetooth, shortcut-keys, headset, button

I have noticed, that although my "Bluetooth Headset" works perfectly fine, buttons on it, like <kbd>Previous</kbd>, <kbd>Next</kbd>, <kbd>Play</kbd> etc do not.

Why is that?

Answer (score 25):

As of Ubuntu 10.04, `uinput` module that handles such buttons is not started by default. To fix the situation:

1. Stop bluetooth service
   `sudo service bluetooth stop`
2. Enable uinput module
   `sudo modprobe uinput`
3. Start bluetooth service back again
   `sudo service bluetooth start`

That should fix the issue temporarily, until restart. To fix it permanently, run:

```
echo 'uinput' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

Comment: worked for me in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Still needed and working in Kubuntu 18.04

Comment: not working on my ubuntu 19.10. uinput does not appear with lsmod. I think it's an obsolete module

Comment: This is still needed in Ubuntu 18.04. It's pretty surprising this problem hasn't been fixed in 8 years. Hopefully in 20.04...

Comment: Still needed, and still helps, in 20.04

Comment: Worked in 22.04 as well

Answer (score 3):

Vava's answer did not fix the issue for me alone (Ubuntu 20.04), I had to use, in addition, `xbindkeys` and `playerctl` https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xbindkeys

First, disable/unassign the shortcuts for media play and pause via the shortcut editor.

```
sudo apt install xbindkeys playerctl
xbindkeys -d > ~/.xbindkeysrc
```

Open `~/.xbindkeysrc` and delete all lines between line 40 and 66 inclusive.

```
xbindkeys --key
```

Get the raw keycode (e.g. `m:0x0 + c:209`). Your headset might toggle between play and pause keycodes, so run `xbindkeys --key` twice to get code for both play and pause.

Put the following into your ~/.xbindkeysrc with the correct key codes.

```
"playerctl play-pause"
   m:0x0 + c:208t
   
"playerctl play-pause"
   m:0x0 + c:209
```

If your headset is already passing XF86Play or some other key (you can use `screenkey` to check, you can use the following instead as an example

```
"playerctl play-pause"
   XF86AudioPlay
```

`playerctl play-pause` will control "the first available player". Read `playerctl -h` for more info/options if needed.

Open `/etc/X11/Xsession` as root. Add the line `xbindkeys` after the line `PROGNAME=Xsession`.

Reboot.

My headset now correctly controls Youtube videos.

Comment: Worked perfectly for my Sony WF-1000XM4s! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe there's a small correction needed (I am not entirely sure). The keycodes you mentioned were spot on, except for the first one, which was `m:0x0 + c:208` for me instead of `m:0x0 + c:208t`. I don't know much about keycodes, but if anyone runs into this issue, try changing the keycode like this and see if it works for you :D