# Pause music with bluetooth headset button

Tags: sound, bluetooth, rhythmbox, music, gmusicbrowser

I have a bluetooth headset (Philips SHB7150 if that matters). Everything works fine; I get audio, volume works, and previous/next works. But the play/pause button does nothing.

I tried looking at it with xev, and it gives me XF86AudioPlay key events. Pressing the corresponding key in the keyboard does play/pause music.

```
KeyPress event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x5a00001,
    root 0x294, subw 0x0, time 6697193, (104,41), root:(1384,93),
    state 0x0, keycode 208 (keysym 0x1008ff14, XF86AudioPlay), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 172
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x5a00001,
    root 0x294, subw 0x0, time 6697272, (104,41), root:(1384,93),
    state 0x0, keycode 208 (keysym 0x1008ff14, XF86AudioPlay), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 172
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

For comparison, xev output with the keyboard button:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x5a00001,
    root 0x294, subw 0x0, time 6700900, (104,41), root:(1384,93),
    state 0x0, keycode 172 (keysym 0x1008ff14, XF86AudioPlay), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

(I don't get the KeyPress, presumably because it was already captured by Unity)

Update: thought I'd try also rhythmbox, and it gets stranger. With gmusicbrowser, it does nothing; with rhythmbox, it pauses if playing, but doesn't play if paused.

Comment: Did you try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6642/buttons-on-my-bluetooth-headset-arent-working?rq=1?

Comment: I have, but it doesn't change anything.

(Also, if that was the issue, prev/next wouldn't work either ;-) )

Comment: this problem looks like this bug-report - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-settings-daemon/+bug/1397142

Comment: too bad I can't promote your comment to response, because it seems to be correct :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since I can't promote [fossfreedom's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/649461/pause-music-with-bluetooth-headset-button?noredirect=1#comment932737_649461), I'll repost it ;-)

This is a bug, currently assigned to unity-settings-daemon: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-settings-daemon/+bug/1397142