# control Youtube in Google Chrome with bluetooth headphone buttons

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, bluetooth, headphones, youtube

Following the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6642/buttons-on-my-bluetooth-headset-arent-working) I am able to control the Ubuntu (14.04) default Videos application with my bluetooth headset play/pause, forward, reverse buttons.

I have tried [Streamkeys](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/streamkeys/ekpipjofdicppbepocohdlgenahaneen?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) and [Key Socket Media Keys](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/key-socket-media-keys/fphfgdknbpakeedbaenojjdcdoajihik) plugins to get the buttons functioning in Chrome, but no success.

What am I missing? What can I do to control Youtube with my headphone buttons?

Answer (score 0):

In windows, (great help, I know) SteamKeys recognises the buttons on my Sony MDR-ZX770BN headphones as: Media Next Track, and Media Play/Pause.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSC3y.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Do you have KDE Plasma?
Did you try [KDE's browser integration extension](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/bh6cxk/kdes_browser_integration_extension_lets_you/)?
With this extension installed I'm able to control media in the browser with media buttons on the keyboard and BT headphones (next, prev only).

In System Settings -> Global Shortcuts I've assigned the play/pause button of my BT headphones to "Play/Pause media playback" and I noticed that it says "Media Pause", while play/pause on my keyboard says "Media Play". Which means they are different keys :/