# After using VLC media keys do not work on rhythmbox

Tags: vlc, rhythmbox, media-buttons

I have a keyboard with the play, pause, next, previous keys to listen to rhythmbox music.
When I watch some video on VLC and then close it and then I open rhythmbox I can listen to music but the media keys no longer work. how can I restore them?
Even if I assign the keystrokes, for example: ctrl + f13, I have the same problem.

Comment: Can you be certain that you have the correct keyboard selected and have you checked the settings in VLC Tools>Preferences>Hotkeys ?

Comment: I have the same problem, still no solution. I did briefly remap the play/pause/etc. keys to run a custom shortcut that only trigger Rhythmbox but I dropped it a as a poor solution.

Comment: Best solution I have found is: https://askubuntu.com/a/1068716/793432