# Media Keys not working

Tags: sound, hardware, 18.10

I am having trouble enabling my media keys on my keyboard. Running Ubuntu 18.10 an I am using a Razor Huntsman elite keyboard which has the pause/play, skip, previous, mute buttons and a dial for the volume.

Comment: Have you installed any drivers specific to your keyboard?

There have been some issues with this keyboard:  https://delightlylinux.wordpress.com/2018/09/23/the-razer-huntsman-elite-keyboard-and-linux-a-major-disappointment/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  I have found specific programs work perfectly with media keys, but others need configuration.  It may be helpful if you provide the programs you are running.

Comment: Sadly I only became aware of the issue with compatibility with my key board and Ubuntu after I got and set up my keyboard. Also I have not yet seen anything yet referring on using a dial or knob for volume control. If there is though then I would be grateful if you or someone else could post a link or share it.

Answer (score 0):

Gnome is abstracting the low level media key press events away from individual programs, and using dbus instead. There is quite a bit of workaround to get the "old way" back.

BUT, There is a bug in gnome-settings-daemon that was corrected in version 3.32.1. Ubuntu 19+ pulls in the fixed version, so anyone running 18 or below is affected, unless they patch GSD.

See my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1241511/619638
There are also instructions for patching and compiling GSD.