# Fastforward, rewind keys do not work

Tags: 18.04, media-buttons

Good day

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

When attempting to FastForward/Rewind any video on Youtube, Kodi, VLC I get a warning icon looking like a grey ghostbusters sign.

As per this [similar post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990284/media-keys-not-working-on-ubuntu-17-10) Gnome apparently intercepts media key commands and prevents execution. The work around for Play/Stop keys can be achieved by using the dconf utility which disables this intercept.

FastForward, Rewind on the other hand are nowhere to be found to remedy this in dconf.

Any suggestions?
Thanks,