# Media play/pause & track prev/next stopped working after reboot

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, media-buttons

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 using a Das Keyboard 4. After a reboot today three of my media keys stopped working, the pause/play key and the prev/next track keys.

However, the mute key and the volume wheel still work.

I tried the following things with no success:

- Going into the keyboards shortcuts settings and setting the keys for these shortcuts explicitly. It does seem to register the keypress but setting or clearing the shortcut doesn't help.
- Messing around in dconf-editor per discussion in [Media Keys not working on Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990284/media-keys-not-working-on-ubuntu-17-10) - I tried clearing the setting for these shortcuts entirely and that did nothing.
- I tried creating a custom shortcut to run `dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.rhythmbox /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause` per that same discussion, but I cannot associate it with the pause/play key from the keyboard shortcuts app. When I try to set the shortcut for this custom command it simply doesn't register the pause/play key being pressed. If I bind it to Ctrl+Alt+Shift+P it does work (but I want my media keys!).

This is incredibly annoying. If anyone has any idea how to fix it I'd be greatly appreciative.

Comment: Does this happen all the time?  Was Chrome open when you were experiencing this?

Comment: @rtaft - yes, this happens all the time. I've rebooted multiple times and tried to use set and use the play/pause after logging in but it does not work.

Comment: Did you try a cold boot?

Comment: Are events from the keyboard still arriving? Can you check with something like xev?

Comment: @SebastianStark - yes, I see the events in xev. I can even set the keys as a shortcut in the gnome keyboard settings applet but the play/pause doesn't work once it's set.

Comment: stupid question perhaps,  but have you checked the num lock / scroll lock status? Not sure if those have any influence on the media keys

Comment: @SebastianStark - I just checked but neither seems to affect whether the play/pause key works.

Comment: Go to a console by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][F3] and type `showkey --keycodes` then press the mute, play, prev, next and mute back again and leave a comment @Fabby with the result.

Comment: @Fabby - Here's the output: https://gist.github.com/autarch/ae1c0f245708b84227fc07ff99474c9c

I assume 28 is the release of enter.

Comment: That's good news!  Now `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys`  Can you still get into [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room?_=1613243665&_=1289574655) with the rep you've got left?

Comment: @Fabby - https://gist.github.com/autarch/e86996e3fe69a53edd09c3de2a5dca5d

And yes, I can join chat.

Comment: **01:52** here. Join now and ping me @Fabby!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do the following:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys previous ''
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys next ''
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-mute ''
```

and then try again as the keys won't be trapped any more so Gnome can do whatever it wants with them.

*If one of the keys stops working, rebind it in Keyboard settings.*

Comment: That did it! Thanks!

Comment: Although I should note that my prev, next, and mute keys had kept working. This broke them but fixed play/pause. Then I went back into the keyboard settings and rebound the prev, next, & mute keys and now it all works. WTF, gnome.

Comment: That's why I wanted you in chat. @DaveRolsky **:-)**  Happy to help, thanks for the upvote and acceptance, don't forget to award the bounty as otherwise I only get half.  **;-)**

Comment: So play/pause has stopped working _again_ after a recent reboot and now this fix no longer solves it. Why, gnome, why?

Comment: And now it's working again after yet another reboot. W. T. F.

Comment: These commands give me errors:
`
expected value:
  (empty input)
  ^
`

Comment: @colan I'm not on Ubuntu any more: Please [ask a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) and refer to this question in your new one *after you've copy-pasted the exact command*...

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution on Ubuntu 19.10 with media keys working after a clean reboot, but not after resuming from sleep, etc.

Restarting `gsd-media-keys` in Terminal:

```
killall gsd-media-keys
/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-media-keys
```

You might want to run the latter command with the run dialog (Alt + F2) because it will start in the foreground.

Comment: Would be cleaner with a `systemctl restart --user gsd-media-keys` kind of command but couldn't get it working since it's only started via dependencies.