# Keyboard specific keys stopped working (Sound BlasterX Vanguard K08)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm using a Sound BlasterX Vanguard K08 keyboard, which features a couple extra keys (five macro keys, some media keys and a volume rocker). My OS is Ubuntu 19.10 (eoan).
It used to work fine for a couple days since the install, but since today or yesterday, almost all **extra keys have stopped working**:

- Two of the five macro keys still work, three don't. The ones who don't work anymore are bound to mouse functions, btw: Left-, right- and middle click. Haven't yet tried to switch them around.
- The media keys and volume rocker don't work anymore.

`showkey` does not register any input for the keys that aren't working anymore.
Not really sure what I changed. It possibly coincides with installing dconf-editor, but I only used that to make monitor-setup-related changes, nothing related to the keyboard.

I do not expect to be able to setup the macro keys in Ubuntu, as I can do that under Windows. When booting into Windows, btw, all keys still work just fine, so it's not a hardware issue.

I looked at the following, somewhat similar problems (and others, which are analogous to the ones below):

[Media keys not registered](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218073/media-keys-not-registered): Similar, but doesn't have an answer yet.

[Media play/pause & track prev/next stopped working after reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150397/media-play-pause-track-prev-next-stopped-working-after-reboot): Solution didn't work for me, no change after applying the settings.

[Media Keys not working on Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990284/media-keys-not-working-on-ubuntu-17-10): Doesn't apply, showkey doesn't register input in my case.

[External article "How to fix media keys not working on Linux"](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/fix-media-keys-not-working-on-linux/): talks about `playerctl`, which wasn't necessary before and wouldn't solve the issue with macro keys.

Comment: I switched the keybindings around and put normal keybindings like 'a', 'b', 'c' on the macro keys that didn't work before. Now they're recognised.
I also put mouse buttons (left and right click) on the ones that worked before, so now they don't work anymore.
It appears to me, that my keyboard used to be recognised as a keyboard+mouse, but not anymore.

Comment: switched to development version of ubuntu 20.04. keys work again :)