# Completely reset all keyboard related configurations? (Media keys and mouse click with macro keys not working)

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I recently asked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218203/keyboard-specific-keys-stopped-working-sound-blasterx-vanguard-k08), but both didn't get a reply and have more information.
My goal is to get my keyboard (Sound Blaster Vanguard K08) fully working again. Currently, the macro keys only work if I put keyboard buttons/combinations on them, but not mouse buttons, and all media keys are dead.

However, when booting from the Ubuntu 19.10 Live USB stick, with which I installed my system, everything works perfectly fine.

How can I get back to that state? Any suggestions are welcome.

My hunch is, that my keyboard used to be recognised as keyboard+mouse or sth like that, because special and mouse related functions don't work anymore.

Comment: I completely reinstalled Ubuntu 19.10, including erasing the disk. Still, the buttons don't work again.

Comment: Now I installed the dev version of 20.04 (```sudo do-release-upgrade -d```). It works again :) :) :)