# Bluetooth headphones media keys not working

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, headphones, sony

I'm using the Sony WH-1000XM3 on Ubuntu 20.04. The headphones support media controls through touch gestures. Volume up/down works fine, but pause/play and next/previous track does nothing. Neither in Spotify nor on YouTube.

I tried to set Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts > Sound and Media > Play (play/pause) to "Audio play" etc but that made no difference.

I noticed that using they headphones media keys don't show anything when running `xev` in Terminal.

Any ideas how this can be resolved?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am facing the same issue with my WH-XB900N

Comment: this seems a deadend for ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/6642/buttons-on-my-bluetooth-headset-arent-working?rq=1