# Media buttons not working on headphones bluetooth

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, bluetooth, headphones, media-buttons

The pause / next / previous multimedia buttons of my headphones do not respond with any program, I tried to fix it in several ways that I found by Google, such as setting xbindkeys or restarting uinput, but nothing was successful.
I use Kubuntu 20.04.
The volume up and down buttons do seem to work.

Comment: It is doubtful the kernel drivers for Bluetooth support theses extra button features of your headphone. Does the mrg have a Ubuntu driver for them?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265360/bluetooth-headphones-media-keys-not-working