# Sony WH1000-XM5, taking off headset pausing, putting on not resuming

Tags: sound, xorg, suspend, headphones, sony

I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6642/buttons-on-my-bluetooth-headset-arent-working) to get the headphone commands to start/stop the players and even control the volume. I somehow cannot get the play/pause when putting on/off to working. Taking the headphones off is working but putting them on does not work (the music is not unpaused).

What is interesting is that I do not observe any commands being sent to X (via `xbindkeys --key`) when I put it on/take it off.

Maybe these messages are sent in some other way, because before adding the Play/Pause commands to the `~/.xbindkeysrc` nothing happened when I took off the headhones and now at least half of the functionality is working.

I would appreciate your input.

Comment: you were able to fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately no, left it be. It works just fine on Windows so I am wondering what might be the case here.